# How do I query three related tables?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm new to databases and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Deliveries Table
-- ID (PK)
-- DriverID (FK to Drivers Table)

Drivers Table
-- ID (PK)
-- LocationID (FK to Locations Table)

Locations Table
-- ID (PK)
-- RestaurantID (FK to Restaurants Table)

Restaurant Table
--ID (PK)

A Restaurant can have multiple locations (1 to many). A location can have multiple drivers (1 to many). a Driver can have multiple deliveries (1 to many). This design is supposed to break things out in 3rd normal form. So if I want to go to the deliveries table and get all of the deliveries associated with a particular restaurant, how would I query or do a join for that? Would I have to add a second foreign key to Deliveries that directly references the Restaurant table? I think after I see the query I can figure out what is going on. Thx

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What parts are you able to do? Where are you stuck? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: I don't have any code written yet, this is me just trying to figure out how I'm going to set the db design up. If my question is too unclear than I'll delete it, but I can't figure out a better way to ask it at this time and I thought it should be obvious what I am asking.

Comment: Wouldn't there be issue if you consider Location.ID as primary key and multiple restaurant ID has the same LOCATION ID?

Comment: Well I can't delete the question anymore or I will be penalized because there are answers already. If I keep it up, I will be penalized by you guys, so I'm in a no win position forced to accept down votes. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left or right outer join to make a combined table and then you can easily query it, or else you can use a query with multiple sub-queries inside it to attain the required result without using join. Here is an example on how to use sub-query for your use-case.

```
SELECT ID FROM Deliveries De 
WHERE De."DriverID" IN (SELECT ID FROM Drivers Dr 
                        WHERE Dr. "LocationID" IN (SELECT ID FROM Locations L 
                                                   WHERE L. "RestaurantID" IN (SELECT ID FROM Restaurant)))
```

I hope this solves your issue without using join statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join or union depending on what you want to achieve. Example:

```
SELECT a."articleId" AS id, a.title, a."articleImage" AS "articleImage/url", c.category AS "category/public_id", a."createdOn", concat("firstName", ' ', "lastName") AS author 
          FROM articles a 
          INNER JOIN users u ON a."userId" = u."userId" 
          INNER JOIN categories c ON a."categoryId" = c."categoryId"
    UNION
SELECT g."gifId" AS id, g.title, g."imageUrl" AS "articleImage/url", g.public_id AS "category/public_id", g."createdOn", concat("firstName", ' ', "lastName") AS author 
          FROM gifs g 
          INNER JOIN users u ON g."userId" = u."userId" 
          ORDER BY "createdOn" DESC
```

You can say how you want to get the results for more detailed query.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do then it maybe like this,
1st you have to join all those table to get corresponding result you want,
the join condition will be

`select <your desire column name>
from Restaurant A,Locations B,Drivers C,Deliveries D
where A.ID = B.RestaurantID 
and B.ID = C.LocationID 
and C.ID = D.DriverID`

Hope this is helpful, fell free to say anything.